# open a terminal on login and execute 2 commands as if I am writing the codes into terminal myself

Tags: pi-4, login

there's probably a way to do this but I've been searching for hours with no solution in sight. I'm also an amateur at this so my level of knowledge on this is minimal.

what I'm looking to do is have a normal terminal open once I log in and then enter these commands

```
cd /home/pi/Downloads/pi-weather-station
npm start
```

here's what it looks like when I do it manually

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd /home/pi/Downloads/pi-weather-station
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads/pi-weather-station $ npm start
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v10.21.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/

> pi-weather-station@1.0.0 start /home/pi/Downloads/pi-weather-station
> node ./server/index.js

pi-weather-station v1.0.0 has started on port 8080
```

Comment: Does executing `/home/pi/Downloads/pi-weather-station/npm start` do what you want? If you can remove the `cd` command, you could easily put it in `rc.local` or `systemd`. But `systemd` is better - look it up on Google

Comment: the command you suggested says no file or directory with that name
I edited the post to show what it looks like when I do it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are login to the default Graphical User Interface **LXDE** of the Raspberry Pi OS.

> what I'm looking to do is have a normal terminal open once I log in and then enter these commands

the bash script `~/.profile` is executed on login, so you can append this line at the end:

```
lxterminal --working-directory=/home/pi/Downloads/pi-weather-station --command='npm start' &
```

Please note the **&** at the end. Without it, `.profile` will not finish. If the terminal immediately closes after running the command, then try this line:

```
lxterminal --working-directory=/home/pi/Downloads/pi-weather-station --command='/bin/bash -c "npm start; /bin/sleep infinity"' &
```

and close it with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

Comment: thank you! it worked and the command makes sense to me seeing it as I needed it applied